# How to create { x = y | y = z | z = 0 } block dynamically from hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chewy-gem

Although the context is likely irrelevant, I'm using the Chewy gem to filter Elasticsearch results using this code:

```
scope = scope.filter {
      (send('facet_properties').send(property_ids[0], :or) == val.map(&:to_i)) |
          (send('facet_properties').send(property_ids[1], :or) == val.map(&:to_i))
    }
```

I'm looking for a way to loop through each element in `property_ids` rather than calling `property_ids[0]`, `property_ids[1]`, etc., separated by an `or` individually. In actual use `property_ids` will not be a fixed length.

Comment: can you first get the count of property_id's and then run a loop N times?

Comment: Looping through wouldn't allow the `|` comparison, at least not with a syntax I'm familiar with. For a non chewy specific solution this seems to work: `scope = scope.filter { property_ids.map { |k| send('facet_properties').send(k, :or) == val.map(&:to_i) }.reduce do |memo, o| memo | o end }`, the accepted answer shows a better chewy specific solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the context, but suspect this may work: `scope = scope.filter { property_ids.reduce(false) { |tf, id| (send('facet_properties').send(id, :or) == val.map(&:to_i)) | tf } }`.

Comment: Thanks @Cary - This looks like a better approach for my initial question and what I'd use if the chewy gem wasn't capable of searching many keys to many values (which I was unaware of until the answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what your structure looks like or exactly what you are trying to achieve but have you tried something like this?

```
vals = val.map(&:to_i)
prop_hash = Hash[property_ids.map{|prop| [prop,vals]}]
# alternately prop_hash = property_ids.each_with_object({}){|prop,obj| obj[prop] = vals}
scope.filter(facet_properties: {prop_hash}).filter_mode(:or)
```

Since `chewy` has a `#filter_mode` method to set the join type for where conditions it seems like this should work for you.

Comment: Interesting. I had just come up with another solution based on a chat in IRC using .reduce, this is chewy specific, but for anyone looking to answer this question more generically the .reduce approach works:

`scope = scope.filter { property_ids.map { |k| send('facet_properties').send(k.to_s, :or) == val.map(&:to_i) }.reduce do |memo, o| memo | o end }`